# URLSession lost the header 'Authorization'

Tags: ios, swift4, urlsession

I have to modify the header **Authorization** with the value starts by "**Token xxxx**" to call some endpoints to get values in my project;

Recently my colleague created a new endpoint, I used exactly the same method to call it but it always returns **status code 500**.

If I redirect the request and add back Authorization in the method:

> -[NSURLSessionTaskDelegate URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:]

then it will work. Which means URLSession does not pass the Authorization key in header while calling.

From the Apple's doc said, we should not modify the header Authorization, but why only this endpoint has this problem ?

Here is the simple code of calling my endpoint with Authorization key:

```
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.myurl.com/api/newAPI")!
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.addValue("Token XXXX", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"

    session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
       ...
```

Comment: HTTP code 500 is internal server error. Whatever it is, it's not in your code. Ask your colleague to debug his server code

Comment: But my other colleague can get the result on PHP, and it works fine on Postman. If I implement URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler: I can also get the result...

Comment: Did you ever found a way to fix this? I'm having the same issue for just one service, and the service works on cURL and postman

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it has to do with the path, double check the path written by your colleague maybe you are missing '/' at the end of the path.

Comment: This is an interesting insight and it might be true, but this in itself doesn't really explain why. See my answer for why this might fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it works after implementing `...willPerformHTTPRedirection...`, that's a hint the API path at `url` you are calling is not the final destination of the request. The initial request you send is being redirected by the server at `url` to another URL, where it is finally being processed.

By default, most HTTP clients strip the `Authorization` header when following a redirect for security reasons – they want to stop you from accidentally leaking your authorization information to a server you didn't intend it to reach. That's why you'll get the error you're seeing (although the 500 error indicates the server is also not configured correctly in the case where the `Authorization` header is missing entirely).

You can test this by calling `curl -v https://www.myurl.com/api/newAPI` and seeing which status code that returns (it will probably be a 301 or 302 from what you describe – i.e., a redirect). Try to find out which URL you're being redirected *to* (the redirect target will be in the `Location` header of the response you get from that `curl` invocation). Then set *that* value in `let url = URL(theActualURL)!` and try again.